# Android SAXParser Malformed XMl error

Tags: java, android, sax

I have a server component which uses SAXParser (javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory) to parse an XML. I am reusing this library in my phonegap app for android. The problem is that when I use the library to communicate to the server and parse the response from the server, it fails with - Malformed XML - exception. However, if I use the same library from normal Java program, the response from the server is processed fine by the parser and there is no error.
I compared the XML payloads in both android and normal javacase and they are exactly the same. I know that this is a very vague and strange question with very little to go on but I am out of ideas. Any ideas or hints would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a DTD or namespace in that XML? It may be possible that the android app has a problem with those and fail to parse because of that. (Is there an exact error message?)

You may check what are the differences between the parsers by checking

- [`isNamespaceAware()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#isNamespaceAware%28%29)
- [`isValidating()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html#isValidating%28%29)

There might be a difference. If there is, use [`SAXParserFactory#setNamespaceAware()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setNamespaceAware%28boolean%29) and [`SAXParserFactory#setValidating()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParserFactory.html#setValidating%28boolean%29) to set the same values.

Comment: The Parser is not at android level. Android app via phonegap javascript simply calls my Java library to connect to server and process the response. Android does not process any XML. I checked my java lib and set isvalidating and isnamespaceaware both to false, still same error from Android (works fine from normal java)

Comment: sax is a somewhat outdated parsing lib, are you open to other lib like vtd-xml?